# How to add a key val pair string -> []float64 to a map?

Tags: dictionary, go

I want to create a map from string keys to float64 array values. I initialize and assign:

```
gloveEmbeddings := make(map[string][]float64)
gloveEmbeddings["a"] := []float64{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
```

But the second line gives the error:
./server.go:51:18: non-name gloveEmbeddings["a"] on left side of :=

How do I assign a float64 vector to the key "a" of the gloveEmbeddings map?

Answer (score 3):

You assign by using [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) `=`, not [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) (`:=`):

```
gloveEmbeddings := make(map[string][]float64)
gloveEmbeddings["a"] = []float64{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Bzv6JCj6SeB).

The `:=` is to create new variables, and you don't want to create a new variable on the 2nd line, but only assign a value to a key in the already created map.